# jQuery attribute value encoding

Tags: jquery

I would like to set tag title attribute with text that contains characters which break html structure. I have encoded some special characters using jQuery parser, but title text also includes quotes ". Do I have to encode them by myself or I can expect jQuery will take care of that when I will use .attr() function?

In this example quotes are not encoded: https://jsfiddle.net/a76nxrz4/2/

```
jQuery('div').attr({ title :'Some text with &lt;div&gt;html&lt;/div&gt; ""'});
```

As I explore DOM I see:

```
<div title="Some text with &amp;lt;div&amp;gt;html&amp;lt;/div&amp;gt; """>
  simple div container
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong or this is expected behavior (no encoding for quotes)?

It Man

Comment: you cant put HTML in an attribute. you will always see the plain text.

Comment: `jQuery('div').attr({ title :'Some text with <div>html</div>'});` will print that tag into the attribute – though it is still shown as HTML markup, since attribute contents are always plain text and not parsed.

Comment: Look for the [jQuery-ui tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)... Maybe that is what you need to have nicer titles.

Comment: title attribute content is treated as text, no html engine runs over it, so it will be shown as it is no matter of the content, but you can use text special chars as \n per instance  to make it more readable. ex: `$('div').attr({ title :'line1\nline2\nline3'});`, if you think it's needed, even the text is single quoted, which means a text render is running before the hover box is shown.